# How to use getters or actions when passing Pinia store as a prop in Vue single file components

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

First time using Pinia in place of Vuex. In Vuex I used to just access $store.getters. Using Pinia I have imported my store in a parent component and passed it down as a prop to the child components something like below.

```
import { useMyStore } from '@/stores/MyStore.js';
const myStore = useMyStore();

...

<template>
  <MyComponent :my-store="myStore">

...
```

This worked fine to access the store data in my templates such as looping through a set of products but I can't work out how to access getters.

```
// *** does not work ****

// 1.  in props

props: ['myStore']

// 2. in methods etc. 

myStore.products.getProductById('Some Id')

// ****  this works ***

// 1. import the store again

import { useMyStore } from '@/stores/MyStore.js';
...

// 2. in data 

myStore : useMyStore()

// 3. In methods etc.

this.myStore.products.getProductById('Some Id')
```

I would like to be able to do this without importing the store in every component where I want to use Getters or Actions.

What is the proper way to handle this using Pinia?

Comment: I'm not sure what you have against it but Pinia is meant to be imported wherever needed

Comment: The proper way to handle this in Pinia or Vuex is to import the store in whichever component you need it.

Comment: @yoduh  I don't have anything against it, just old habits or ways of doing things die hard.

Comment: @Fanoflix  I guess i will just have to adopt the pattern.